# Controller Action Based on Media Query (Rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, devise, media-queries, device-detection

I have a specialized dashboard for my Rails application that is shown to users using a media query. I'd like to have devise redirect users on mobile devices (through media queries) to that specific dashboard upon sign in.

What's a good way to get this done, while attempting to avoid having rails actually detect anything? I've looked into gems like `browser` a bit, but I'd like something a little more comprehensive and customizable, such as a media query.

Any suggestions of places to start looking, or what kind of code I could put in my  View / JS / CSS to make this happen?

I'd highly prefer to fire off a specific controller action for specific media queries, but I feel like that may be an unachievable dream.

Comment: Maybe I could have two different devise sign in buttons rendered based on media queries?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Variants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants) to achieve this.

With `variant` option, you can do something like this to render different dashboard views :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do |html|
    html.desktop # renders app/views/projects/show.html+desktop.erb
    html.mobile { extra_setup; render ... }
  end
end
```

Or, you can develop mobile friendly views for all actions and do this (using `browser` gem):

```
before_action :define_variant

def define_variant
  request.variant = :tablet if browser.phone?
end
```